# Unable to load shared library 'db2app64.dll'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, db2, entity-framework-core

Currently working with IBM DB2, Openshift and Linux using the IBM DB .NET Core Provider.

When running the application it errors with

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library
>   'db2app64.dll' or one of its dependencies.

In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable:

> libdb2app64.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory at
>   IBM.Data.DB2.Core.UnsafeNativeMethods.DB232.SQLFreeConnAttribsADONET(DB2SQLGetConnAttribsADONETParams&
>   pParam)

Comment: Which Db2-client (IBM Data Server Client) have you installed ?

Comment: It's the IBM.EntityFrameworkCore nuget package i.e. https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.EntityFrameworkCore/1.3.0.100

Comment: Did you modify your PATH environment to include  %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\IBM.Data.DB2.Core\<version>\build\clidriver\bin   (You will need to stop and restart VS after changing this environment variable).

Comment: @mao this is not running windows or visual studio.  It is running on linux in a container.

Comment: Code that runs natively on Linux won't use DLL files .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to reference the IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx for Linux builds.

.net was attempting to load the windows library db2app64.dll hence the reason why it was throwing the error.  Unable to load shared library 'db2app64.dll'

[image]

Comment: For macOS users ... don't despair, there is also an OSX version.